# Unable to find specific string in list that has been read in using csv reader?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading in a list of words (dict) and trying to find out if a specific word is in the list. This is the code:

```
    dict = []
    with open('words.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
        for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
            dict.append(row)

    print('hello' in dict)
```

I know hello is in the list dict but the last line of code returns False.

If i enter the following code it gives True so it must be something with how its reading it in:

```
    dict=['hel','hello','heo','sds','sdswe']
    print('hello' in dict)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Why would you call a list dict?! :X

Comment: This code overwrites the built-in `dict` and assigns a list to it. Slightly confusing..

Comment: Why don't you add `print(dict)` to see what it contains?

Comment: Ok so ive updated the code to use DictWB which made no difference

Comment: It prints `True` because 'hello' is in your list. It will likely read `False` because `row` is a list.

Comment: If i print dict [0:10] it prints the first 10 words in the dictionary. It has over 150000 words though so i dont want to print the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is the fact that **you are appending lists from the *`.txt`* file instead of strings, ending up with a list of lists instead of your intended list of strings**.

What csv.reader does is that it reads the contents of the *`.txt`* file as lists.

So, for instance, if the .txt file has

```
Your
Name
```

csv.reader will interpret it like this:

```
[['Your'], ['Name']]
```

Thus a list of lists and not a list of strings.

So,you can do this if you want a list of strings:

```
yourlist.append(row[0].strip()) #striping will remove the newline
```

This will give you the element of the row, instead of the list itself. Let me know if this helps you out.

Finally, this is what you can have:

```
yourlist = []
with open('words.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        yourlist.append(row[0].strip())
print('hello' in yourlist)
```

Comment: @Darragh glad I could help. Welcome to the family.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues with your code:

1. Never name a variable after a class, e.g. use `lst` to represent a list instead of `dict`.
2. `row` returns a list, while you only want the first entry in each `row` instance; i.e. use `row[0]`.

The below code demonstrates the second issue. If in doubt, as below, use `print(type(row))` to see the object type you are using.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

csvstr = StringIO("""hel
hello
heo
sds
sdswe
""")

lst = []

for row in csv.reader(csvstr):
    print(type(row))  # <class 'list'>
    lst.append(row[0])

print('hello' in lst)  # True
```

Comment: Cheers thats very helpful!